# Create a new level column based on unique row sets

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I want to create a new column with new variables (preferably letters) to count the frequency of each set later on.

Lets say I have a data frame called `datatemp` which is like:

> ```
>  datatemp = data.frame(colors=rep( c("red","blue"), 6), val = 1:6)
>     colors val
> 1     red   1
> 2    blue   2
> 3     red   3
> 4    blue   4
> 5     red   5
> 6    blue   6
> 7     red   1
> 8    blue   2
> 9     red   3
> 10   blue   4
> 11    red   5
> 12   blue   6
> ```

And I can see my unique row sets where `colors` and `val` columns have identical inputs together, such as:

> ```
>  unique(datatemp[c("colors","val")]) 
>    colors val
> 1    red   1
> 2   blue   2
> 3    red   3
> 4   blue   4
> 5    red   5
> 6   blue   6
> ```

What I really want to do is to create a new column in the same data frame where each unique set of row above has a level, such as:

> ```
>     colors val freq
> 1     red   1   A
> 2    blue   2   B
> 3     red   3   C
> 4    blue   4   D
> 5     red   5   E
> 6    blue   6   F
> 7     red   1   A
> 8    blue   2   B
> 9     red   3   C
> 10   blue   4   D
> 11    red   5   E
> 12   blue   6   F
> ```

I know that's very basic, however, I couldn't come up with an useful idea for a huge dataset.

So make the question more clear, I am giving another representation of desired output below:

> ```
>    colA     colB  newcol
>     10        11     A
>     12        15     B
>     10        11     A
>     13        15     C
> ```

Values in the new column should be based on uniqueness of first two columns before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

www's solution maps the unique values in your `value` column to letters in `freq` column. If you want to do create a factor variable for each unique combination of `colors` and `val`, you could do something along these lines:

```
library(plyr)
datatemp = data.frame(colors=rep( c("red","blue"), 6), val = 1:6)
datatemp$freq <- factor(paste(datatemp$colors, datatemp$val), levels=unique(paste(datatemp$colors, datatemp$val)))
datatemp$freq <- mapvalues(datatemp$freq, from = levels(datatemp$freq), to = LETTERS[1:length(levels(datatemp$freq))])
```

I first create a new factor variable for each unique combination of `val` and `colors`, and then use plyr::mapvalues to rename the factor levels to letters.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I've asked for, although plyr is a risky package to call from library because of the conflicts with dplyr. So I've changed that part a bit as:
datatemp$freq <- plyr::mapvalues(datatemp$freq, from = levels(datatemp$freq), to = LETTERS[1:length(levels(datatemp$freq))]) ,  since I really didn't want to call plyr library. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

We can concatenate the `val` and `color` column and create it as factor, then we can change the factor level by letters.

```
datatemp$Freq <- as.factor(paste(datatemp$val, datatemp$colors, sep = "_"))
levels(datatemp$Freq) <- LETTERS[1:length(levels(datatemp$Freq))]
datatemp
#    colors val Freq
# 1     red   1    A
# 2    blue   2    B
# 3     red   3    C
# 4    blue   4    D
# 5     red   5    E
# 6    blue   6    F
# 7     red   1    A
# 8    blue   2    B
# 9     red   3    C
# 10   blue   4    D
# 11    red   5    E
# 12   blue   6    F
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response but my case a little bit complicated than this and now realized that I should have been more clear in the question. As a summary, I have two different classes in two different columns such as:
>        colA     colB  newcol
>         10        11       A
>         12        15       B
>         10        11       A
>         13        15       C

so on, so I want to check the condition of being unique of first two columns together, then I want a new column, with a new set of variables (letters in this case) to indicate the group of the unique row.

Comment: @DSA Please see my update to see if it is what you need.